# how to get longer Dataset labels in notebook display?

Tags: notebooks

In a dataset, I have many 7-character labels with a common prefix. In a notebook, I see only the first three characters in column headers, which means I see only the prefix. (Win 10; Mma 12) The columns are plenty wide, since the values display with more digits. Can I change the header display to show full labels?

Here is a simple example. (Just increase the range if you don't see label truncation.)

```
labels = StringTemplate["a``"] /@ (IntegerString[#, 10, 6] &) /@ Range[300]
Dataset[{AssociationMap[RandomReal[] &, labels], AssociationMap[RandomReal[] &, labels]}]
```

> {"a000001", "a000002", "a000003", "a000004", "a000005", "a000006", 
>   "a000007", "a000" ....
>
> [image]

Comment: I use `Dataset` only for displaying data. For this kind of usage, you could just modify the keys before displaying them by replacing `Dataset` in your code with `Query[All /* Dataset, KeyMap[Curry[StringDelete]["a" ~~ "0" ...]]]`

Comment: For display purposes `CellPrint` can be used: `ds = Dataset[...]; ToBoxes[ds] /. Pane[a_, b_] :> Pane[a] // BoxData // Cell // CellPrint`. The problem is that MMA (or Front end?) takes `Pane` into account in a wrong way somehow when it form `Dataset` from internal box structure. This can be seen and corrected also by using "Show Expression" (Ctrl + Shift + E).